# Is it possible to have more than 4 Zombie Dogs?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I'm playing a [sacrifice build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#aiVjdY!ZWd!aaZZYZ) Witch Doctor, and recently added Mass Confusion with Devolution rune.  However, I have yet to get any additional zombie dogs from killing a confused opponent.

Each time, I've opened with Soul Harvest, then hit Mass Confusion, then Acid Cloud.  That usually kills most of them before my zombie dogs are in melee for more than a second or two.

Yet I always wind up with 4 zombie dogs.  Is that the hard limit to the number available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe some answers here are outdated, and with my personal knowledge I believe the upper limit is at least **six**:

- Default limit is 3
- [Zombie Handler](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/zombie-handler) passive gives you +1
- [Midnight Feast](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/midnight-feast) passive gives you +1
- [Fierce Loyalty](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/fierce-loyalty) passive gives you +1

This would be a total of 6.

Answer (score 3):

The Witch Doctor has several ways to get Zombie dogs even if they don't have the "Summon Zombie Dogs" Skill. The limit of 3 (or 4, with the talent) is just a built-in property of the class.

It doesn't matter *how* you get them, but the maximum is 3+1 dogs every way you look at it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](http://diablo3area.com/diablo3-witchdoctor-skills.php), max is 3 zombie dogs, upped to 4 with the passive skill Zombie Handler. So, 4 is the max. Matches info from [d3db](http://d3db.com/tool/calculator/witch-doctor/18459)'s skill calculator.

Comment: It's a good thing it so easy to respec. That's a disappointing hidden limitation.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it's possible, I have 5 on my witch doctor. You can see this in my screenshot below:

[image: 5 Zombie Dogs]

Comment: For this to be an acceptable answer you should add information as to how you have 5 zombie dogs active. What abilities, passives, equipment, cube powers etc. do you have equipped? What situation does this happen in, just combat, after an elite pack etc?